# Adding line breaks when editing .vb files in Visual Studio 2010 very slow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 installed.

I'm experiencing a huge lag of between 0.5 to 2.0 seconds every time I either enter a line break or remove a line, but only when editing VB.NET files (extension `.vb`).

Oddly, 'normal' typing on just a single line (along with Intellisense) is still very responsive.

Has anyone got any tips or clues as to how I can speed this up? My google-fu is letting me down.

The machine specs are fairly healthy, and the issue is not prevalent when editing any other filetype inside Visual Studio (c# etc).

Edit: Just as an update, all addons and extensions are disabled.

Comment: don't suppose you've installed any addons recently?

Comment: Any chance this is happening for one specific solution? Or even when you create brand new vb file?

Comment: @johnyTee Yep it happens even if I create an empty vb class (inside  the same project)